# ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError when using namespaces for models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have a namespace for a part of the project.

```
class Namespace::Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: :namespace_category, class_name: 'Namespace::Category'
  ...
end

class Namespace::Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, :class_name => 'Namespace::Product'
  ...
end
```

The migration for Product looks like

```
create_table :namespace_products do |t|
  t.belongs_to :namespace_category, index: true
  ...
end
```

So, when I do this

```
p = Namespace::Product.create(some_params)
c = Namespace::Category.find(id)
c.products << p
```

it throws me an error, saying `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute 'category_id'`, however I have an attribute

```
t.integer  "namespace_category_id"
```

in my `schema.rb`, which was created by the migration.

Comment: Shouldn't `has_many :products` be changed to `has_many :namespace_products`?

Comment: @31piy you can call it any way if the class is specified

Comment: Could it be that you are actually using `belongs_to: :category, class_name: 'Namespace::Category'`? In that case you need to use the `belongs_to: :category, class_name: 'Namespace::Category', foreign_key: 'namespace_category_id'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just omit the namespaces from the associations:

```
class Namespace::Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category, class_name: 'Namespace::Category'
  ...
end

class Namespace::Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, class_name: 'Namespace::Product'
  ...
end
```

---

```
class FixColumnName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :namespace_products, :namespace_category_id, :category_id
  end
end
```

Comment: So I just specified the foreign key as you commented and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone on Rails 5+ looking back at this, you can also specify the namespace on the migration level if you don't want them on the associations:

```rb
def change
  create_table :namespace_products do |t|
    t.references :category, foreign_key: { to_table: :namespace_categories }
  end
end

# or

def change
  add_reference :namespace_products, :category, foreign_key: { to_table: :namespace_categories }
end
```

```rb
class Namespace::Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end

class Namespace::Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.0/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just had to specify `foreign_key` while defining `has_many :products` association in `Namespace::Category`, thanks to Max